# Cannot convert from method group to thread start

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

im trying to start a new therad like that:

```
var s = new Thread(this.TakeScreenshot);
s.Start();
```

It throws "Cannot convert from method group to thread start".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating new thread with method with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854878/creating-new-thread-with-method-with-parameter)

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: What is the signature of the `TakeScreenshot` method?